# Call a flow of one mule project in another mule project

Tags: maven, plugins, mule, mulesoft

I have a mule project-A where in I need to call a flow from another mule project-B. I have added `<classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>` in the project-B's pom. And I have added a dependency with project-B's group-Id, version, artifact-Id, classifier in project-A's pom and also created an "import" config in project-A with flow name of project-B which I want to use. Still I am unable to call the flow of project-B in project-A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are implementing this to just test in your local machine, then follow the below steps. You can also look at the concept of **Mule Domain Project**, which does resource sharing for those apps falling under the same domain ; enabling you to call other apps flow-refs, global configurations and more.

**Note** : All this below said has to be in Mule 4.

> First, export your `Project-B` as a mule deployable jar.

### Steps

1. Right click on `Project-A` and goto - > `mule`
2. Add a maven dependency.
3. Choose your `Project-B`.jar from your local repository and
   add.

   > This will get your project imported as a maven dependency
   > in your pom.xml file.
4. Make sure your jar added under your project libraries of 'A' in
   the package explorer.
5. Goto to the global elements of `Project-A` and select import
   configurations.
6. Add the `Import` configuration to your elements and specify
   your `Project-B` main XML file you want to use in `Project-A`.
7. Finally refresh/restart your main project and check if you can
   reference the flows.

If you still can't get this work, try updating to the latest version of studio, like 4.3.1 which is a much stable version.

Detailed explanation is given here -> [Mule Shared Projects](https://dzone.com/articles/common-property-configuration-and-shared-resources)

---

### Update

You can also try doing the same in your cloudhub runtime. You don't need a Domain project concept to do this. Basically you kind of imported your `Project-B into Project-A` completely ; Altogether making it a one mashed up Mega project.

Comment: I am using a domain project and both my project belong to the same domain, in that case do I still have to add a deployable jar of Project-B to A?

Comment: No I guess. The method I described above is applicable if you want to pull your other project into your main project completely. It's basically making your secondary as a part of primary project. So you cannot address them to be two independent projects. But for a domain project this is essentially not required.

Comment: What's stopping you from pulling the `Project-B` into `Project-A` entirely as a dependency. After all you are indeed calling the other projects flows using flow-ref. Mule domain projects totally acts as two independent projects which are loosely coupled. But my method also works in cloudhub runtime.

Comment: I wanna achieve this without adding project-B's JAR to project-A because if I add the jar and later I modify some code in project-B lets say I changed the flow names so it will not reflect in project-A as the flow names were different at the time of creating the JAR.

Comment: Amer, if you need exactly like that, then you must use `mule domain project`. I know you already tried domain project. But, there are some good docs on this. Check this <https://apisero.com/implementing-and-deploying-the-domain-project-with-mulesoft/>. Try the link each step and let me know. Also, sometimes if all you need is calling flows and transmitting payload, you always have http request and VM queue connectors (inter app messaging)